# Why do I have yellow dots on my citrus tree and when I turn the leaf there are small white dots

Tags: trees, citrus, leaf

I just recently bought a citrus tree indoors. I had mealy bugs before where I used a mixture of neem oil soap and alcohol which helped a lot but now the new leaves are not getting darker green like the other.
I have noticed recently that they have yellow dots on them, when I turned my leaf it's like an infestation that is going to start but you cannot see it properly.
I normally only use the citrus feed baby bio plant food.

[image: Leaf with yellow discolouration]

[image: Underside of leaf]